# Twitter Bootstrap 3.0 how do I "badge badge-important" now

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In version two I could use

> badge badge-important

I see that the .badge element no longer has contextual (-success,-primary,etc..) classes.

How do i achieve the same thing in version 3?

Eg. I want warning badges and important badges in my UI

Comment: They should have provided `.danger`, `.success` etc. class style definitions out of the box for general use cases like this.

Answer (score 266, accepted):

Just add this **one-line** class in your CSS, and use the bootstrap `label` component.

```
.label-as-badge {
    border-radius: 1em;
}
```

Compare this `label` and `badge` side by side:

```
<span class="label label-default label-as-badge">hello</span>
<span class="badge">world</span>
```

[image]

They appear the same. But in the CSS, `label` uses `em` so it scales nicely, and it still has all the "-color" classes. So the label will scale to bigger font sizes better, and can be colored with label-success, label-warning, etc. Here are two examples:

```
<span class="label label-success label-as-badge">Yay! Rah!</span>
```

[image]

Or where things are bigger:

```
<div style="font-size: 36px"><!-- pretend an enclosing class has big font size -->
    <span class="label label-success label-as-badge">Yay! Rah!</span>
</div>
```

[image]

---

**11/16/2015**: Looking at how we'll do this in Bootstrap 4

Looks like `.badge` classes are completely gone. But there's a built-in `.label-pill` class [(here)](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/eea6690d0e47b25a02bb42e610fde7e5ecd247d7/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L4210-L4214) that looks like what we want.

```
.label-pill {
  padding-right: .6em;
  padding-left: .6em;
  border-radius: 10rem;
}
```

In use it looks like this:

```
<span class="label label-pill label-default">Default</span>
<span class="label label-pill label-primary">Primary</span>
<span class="label label-pill label-success">Success</span>
<span class="label label-pill label-info">Info</span>
<span class="label label-pill label-warning">Warning</span>
<span class="label label-pill label-danger">Danger</span>
```

[image]

---

**11/04/2014**: Here's an update on why cross-pollinating alert classes with `.badge` is not so great. I think this picture sums it up:

[image]

Those alert classes were not designed to go with badges. It renders them with a "hint" of the intended colors, but in the end consistency is thrown out the window and readability is questionable. Those alert-hacked badges are not visually cohesive.

The `.label-as-badge` solution is only extending the bootstrap design. We are keeping intact all the decision making made by the bootstrap designers, namely the consideration they gave for readability and cohesion across all the possible colors, as well as the color choices themselves. The `.label-as-badge` class only adds rounded corners, and nothing else. There are no color definitions introduced. Thus, a single line of CSS.

Yep, it is easier to just hack away and drop in those `.alert-xxxxx` classes -- you don't have to add *any* lines of CSS. Or you *could* care more about the little things and add one line.

Comment: this is cool as long as you dont want to use badges in group-lists, then they dont float... i can see this braking over time as bootstrap is changed. nice hack though.

Comment: Yes, good point @nodrog. The `list-group` with `badges` is a nice out-of-the-box feature in bootstrap. For those watching, here's what that looks like: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group-badges

Comment: I am not convined by the "cross-pollination" argument. Reusage and recombination of CSS classes/attributes is happening all the time. The hidden argument behind your term might be, that you prefer semantic css class and subclass names. It's basically "flexibility/reusability and semantical correctness". A semantical class name should support the role of the element. "label-as-badge" indicates an element transformation. -- Sidenote: The answer is basically my comment from 22 Sept with a solution to the "not so round edges on labels" problem by adding a line of css.

Comment: My issue is specifically with "cross-pollinating alert classes with `.badge`". When you interbreed those two species, you get the visual outcome you see above. I am not speaking against the application of multiple classes on an element. Clearly CSS classes can be designed to do exactly "cross pollination" in a beautiful, orthogonal way. In that spirit, Bootstrap 3 could have provided classes for the standard colors for `.badge` and it would have fit in beautifully.

Comment: If you want to get the special list-group floating just add this!

`.list-group-item > .label-as-badge {
  float: right;
}
.list-group-item > .label-as-badge + .label-as-badge {
  margin-right: 5px;
}`

Comment: Excellent answer. Might also want to throw in there the padding to match .badge as follows: `.label-as-badge { border-radius: 1em; padding: 3px 7px; }`

Comment: The solution provided is semantically wrong.

You must not use one element as another. Never rely on "it is almost similar" - it is open to modifications.
You'd better create your own one (or two or three), inherited from the base ONE, that provided by the included library.

Comment: Maybe given your update, it would be best to change `.label-as-badge` to `.label-pill`, as a sort of polyfill until users are ready to migrate to the Bootstrap 4 way of doing business?  No sense maintaining your own class when you can fall back on out-of-the-box behavior after migrating...

Answer (score 260):

In short: Replace `badge-important` with either `alert-danger` or `progress-bar-danger`.

It looks like this: **[Bootply Demo](http://www.bootply.com/E2K1xnuZ9S)**.

---

You might combine the CSS class `badge` with `alert-*` or `progess-bar-*` to color them:

With `class="badges alert-*"`

```
  <span class="badge alert-info">badge</span> Info
  <span class="badge alert-success">badge</span> Success 
  <span class="badge alert-danger">badge</span> Danger   
  <span class="badge alert-warning">badge</span> Warning
```

**Alerts Docu:** http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts

With `class="badges progress-bar-*"` (as suggested by @clami219)

```
  <span class="badge progress-bar-info">badge</span> Info
  <span class="badge progress-bar-success">badge</span> Success
  <span class="badge progress-bar-danger">badge</span> Danger
  <span class="badge progress-bar-warning">badge</span> Warning
```

**Progress-Bar Docu:** http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress-alternatives

Comment: I didn't like the way the alert was decorating the badges, so I opted to use labels instead. http://getbootstrap.com/components/#labels

Comment: This is a bit of a hack-ish answer. Sure it works, and it's simple. But you're supposed to use those contextual alert classes with alerts. You may be signing yourself up for broken styles in the future. @JasonHuang's answer is just as simple, and provides you with greater control.

Comment: You have a point @mikesigs but I guess we could simply make a css class for all the web colours and add that to our class attribute too. There are 3 excellent answers here and all deserve consideration. I think also that bootstrap 3 changed the css so dramatically from v2 that there really isn't any notion of future-proofing your styles unless you roll your own anyway.

Comment: What prompted me to make the above reply was that Visual Studio Web Essentials shows a warning for the code above. Namely, "When using 'alert-danger', you must also specify the class 'alert'."

Comment: @MaxFavilli it's either a button or a badge. never both. if you just want to colorize your button using an alert-color use: `<span class="btn btn-large alert-warning">Button with Alert Color</span>` . buttons have own colors via `btn-danger`, `btn-info` etc.

Comment: What I wanted is <button class="btn btn-default">hello <span class="badge">with a backgroud color</span></button>

Comment: Inline Badges. I believe they are white or grey. The colors do not have an important flag on them. So they don't override. You could propably switch to a label on the button inside - not so "round" but should work: http://jsfiddle.net/4ojavw7e/

Comment: Aaaah!! No!! When you cross-pollinate classes like this, you throw out design considerations that the bootstrap folks made. See the illustration in my answer below. I propose a very simple one-line CSS solution that keeps the bootstrap design intact.

Comment: People land on this page, because the bootstrap folks made a lot of design considerations, which throw out design considerations they did before :) - I'm just recombined existing css classes, in order to get close to the former "badge-important". Here we go with the stuff they give use out of the box: that's it. I don’t think there is one true way to craft CSS. This page offers lots of ways to solve the issue. But please stop shouting "Aaah! No! This is not the way! you are doing something wrong".

Comment: @Jens-AndréKoch you're right about my "Aaah!! No!!". It _does_ sound like I'm telling people "you're doing it wrong", and I have no place to say that. Sorry.

Comment: Wanted to add a comment with another similar alternative but character limit forced me to post a [new answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33713484/1369473). I'd love to read your comments.

Answer (score 46):

Bootstrap 3 removed those color options for badges. However, we can add those styles manually. Here's my solution, and here is the [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/uhizoRA/59/edit):

```
.badge {
  padding: 1px 9px 2px;
  font-size: 12.025px;
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #999999;
  -webkit-border-radius: 9px;
  -moz-border-radius: 9px;
  border-radius: 9px;
}
.badge:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.badge-error {
  background-color: #b94a48;
}
.badge-error:hover {
  background-color: #953b39;
}
.badge-warning {
  background-color: #f89406;
}
.badge-warning:hover {
  background-color: #c67605;
}
.badge-success {
  background-color: #468847;
}
.badge-success:hover {
  background-color: #356635;
}
.badge-info {
  background-color: #3a87ad;
}
.badge-info:hover {
  background-color: #2d6987;
}
.badge-inverse {
  background-color: #333333;
}
.badge-inverse:hover {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
```

Answer (score 25):

The context classes for `badge` are indeed removed from Bootstrap 3, so you'd have to add some custom CSS to create the same effect like...

```
.badge-important{background-color:#b94a48;}
```

## [Bootply](http://bootply.com/88526)

Comment: Why did they get rid of them?

Comment: +! I'm also wondering why they got rid of them.  You can use label but it doesn't line up properly on a pill container.  At least it's not centered vertically.

Comment: lame. the up migration from 2 to 3 is a complete pain.

Comment: The answer by Jens-André Koch is a Bootstrap 3.0 only solution.  I think this is the right way?

Comment: @Peter: See https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/6342. TLDR: badges are intended to be used as 'unread' counters, and shouldn't be used to convey other statuses.

Comment: yes fair enough but its nice to say 3 unimportant unread items and 2 unread important items

Answer (score 20):

Another possible way, in order to make the colors a bit more intense, is this one:

```
<span class="badge progress-bar-info">10</span>
<span class="badge progress-bar-success">20</span>
<span class="badge progress-bar-warning">30</span>
<span class="badge progress-bar-danger">40</span>
```

See [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/77AAGxkkgg)

Answer (score 18):

If using a SASS version (eg: [thomas-mcdonald's one](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass)), then you may want to be slightly more dynamic (honor existing variables) and create all badge contexts using the same technique as used for labels:

```
// Colors
// Contextual variations of badges
// Bootstrap 3.0 removed contexts for badges, we re-introduce them, based on what is done for labels
.badge-default {
  @include label-variant($label-default-bg);
}

.badge-primary {
  @include label-variant($label-primary-bg);
}

.badge-success {
  @include label-variant($label-success-bg);
}

.badge-info {
  @include label-variant($label-info-bg);
}

.badge-warning {
  @include label-variant($label-warning-bg);
}

.badge-danger {
  @include label-variant($label-danger-bg);
}
```

The LESS equivalent should be straightforward.

Answer (score 5):

Like the answer above but here is using bootstrap 3 names and colours:

```css
/*css to add back colours for badges and make use of the colours*/
.badge-default {
  background-color: #999999;
}

.badge-primary {
  background-color: #428bca;
}

.badge-success {
  background-color: #5cb85c;
}

.badge-info {
  background-color: #5bc0de;
}

.badge-warning {
  background-color: #f0ad4e;
}

.badge-danger {
  background-color: #d9534f;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When using the LESS version you can import mixins.less and create your own classes for colored badges:

```
.badge-warning {
    .label-variant(@label-warning-bg);
}
```

Same for the other colors; just replace warning with danger, success, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is a terribly late answer but I think I'll still put my two cents in... I could have posted this as a comment because this answer doesn't essentially add any new solution but it does add value to the post as yet another alternative. But in a comment I wouldn't be able to give all the details because of character limit.

**NOTE: This needs an edit to bootstrap CSS file - move style definitions for `.badge` above `.label-default`. Couldn't find any practical side effects due to the change in my limited testing.**

While [broc.seib's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26495054/1369473) is probably the best way to achieve the requirement of OP with minimal addition to CSS, it is possible to achieve the same effect without any extra CSS at all just like [Jens A. Koch's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21956578/1369473) or by using `.label-xxx` contextual classes because they are easy to remember compared to `progress-bar-xxx` classes. I don't think that `.alert-xxx` classes give the same effect.

All you have to do is just use `.badge` and `.label-xxx` classes together (but in this order). Don't forget to make the changes mentioned in NOTE above.

`<a href="#">Inbox <span class="badge label-warning">42</span></a>` looks like this:

[image: Badge with warning bg]

**IMPORTANT: This solution may break your styles if you decide to upgrade and forget to make the changes in your new local CSS file. My solution for this challenge was to copy all `.label-xxx` styles in my custom CSS file and load it after all other CSS files. This approach also helps when I use a CDN for loading BS3.**

**P.S: ** Both the top rated answers have their pros and cons. It's just the way you prefer to do your CSS because there is no "only correct way" to do it.

Comment: i think you don't need to move .badge if you placed label-xxxxx before badge