# Bootstrap 4 badge is not changing color

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 and I want to create a badge with blue color so I used:

```
<td><a href="patient_history.php?pid=<?php echo $patient['patient_id']; ?>"><i class="badge badge-info">Edit History</i></a></td>
```

inside a table of `class="table table-hover"`, and the result was the default badge color and not blue.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

use `.label-pill` instead.

```
<span class="label label-pill label-primary">Primary</span>
```

copy the following line in your css and try again

```
.label-as-badge {
    border-radius: 1em;
}
```

Your question already seems to have an answer, Try the below link :

[how to use .label-pill class in Bootstrap-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18730116/twitter-bootstrap-3-0-how-do-i-badge-badge-important-now)

Comment: Just one more question: how can I change the hover color of a table hover class, I tried everything on stack but nothing works

Comment: nope. Where should I add the css code I have 4 css sheets added to my page including the bootstrap

Answer (score 5):

Use progress-bar instead of badge. For example :

```
<i class="badge progress-bar-info">Edit History</i>

<span class="badge progress-bar-success">Active</span>
<span class="badge progress-bar-danger">Inactive</span>
```

Comment: valid for bootstrap 3

Answer (score 3):

Try with creating custom classes.

```css
.badge {
  padding: 1px 9px 2px;
  font-size: 12.025px;
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #999999;
  -webkit-border-radius: 9px;
  -moz-border-radius: 9px;
  border-radius: 9px;
}

.badge:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.badge-error {
  background-color: #b94a48;
}

.badge-error:hover {
  background-color: #953b39;
}

.badge-warning {
  background-color: #f89406;
}

.badge-warning:hover {
  background-color: #c67605;
}

.badge-success {
  background-color: #468847;
}

.badge-success:hover {
  background-color: #356635;
}

.badge-info {
  background-color: #3a87ad;
}

.badge-info:hover {
  background-color: #2d6987;
}

.badge-inverse {
  background-color: #333333;
}

.badge-inverse:hover {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
```

```html
<span class="badge">1</span>
<span class="badge badge-success">2</span>
<span class="badge badge-warning">4</span>
<span class="badge badge-error">6</span>
<span class="badge badge-info">8</span>
<span class="badge badge-inverse">10</span>
```

Comment: @droidnation Try this way.

Answer (score 1):

Use it

Use the `.label` class,  followed by one of the six contextual classes `.label-default, .label-primary, .label-success, .label-info, .label-warning` or `.label-danger`, within a `<span>` element to create a label

```
 <span class="label label-default">Edit History</span>
```

Comment: Bootstrap v4.3.1 does not have a label class. Any comments?